# Most ideal way to query IN statement

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

We receive a bunch of numbers from another service that should be in an `IN` but the problem is, the numbers could be a max of 100k.

The query is so slow when using `IN`. It takes about a minute.

`SELECT * FROM messages WHERE numbers IN (111,222,333...)`

Do you have any suggestion what could be changed so it'll be optimized?

PS: The goal is to filter the messages that uses the numbers that we receive from another service.

Thanks!

Comment: Store the data in a table and use `JOIN`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry.. I mean the numbers we receive are not from ours but from another service. The goal is to only filter the messages that have the numbers from the other serivce. Will update my question to be more clear. Thanks!

Comment: Try creating index over field `numbers `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite frequently, using a JOIN against a `values` clause is faster than an `IN` clause:

```
select m.*
from messages m
  join (
     values (111),(222),(333),(444),(...)
  ) as t(id) on m.numbers = t.id;
```

However this **only** works if you can be sure that there are no duplicate values in the list of IDs

Comment: Sir, what is the `t` here?

Comment: t is an alias for the subquery.

Comment: @mengmeng: see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES

Comment: ok I get it now. but there is a possibility that the `m.numbers` is not unique. :(

Comment: @mengmeng: the values in `messages.numbers` aren't relevant. It's the list of values you compare to where you need to make sure no duplicates occur. joining against `values (111),(111)`  will return a different result than `in (111,111)`

Comment: Oh okay. Thank you sir! Will try it out. :) As always, you've been a great help!